Deploying NextJS with Socket.IO application in IIS 10
I already deployed my application in IIS using the tutorial of Halfblood Programmer. I am using HttpPlatformHandler v1.2, the application is already running but the problem is the websocket. Socket.io pooling is not found, returning 404. I already enabled and installed the IIS WebSocket Protocol support, added <webSocket enabled="true" /> in my web.config but nothing works. Please help me. Btw, my application is running on windows server 2022 and iis 10
    //server.js
    const { createServer } = require('http');
    const { parse } = require('url');
    const next = require('next');
    const { Server } = require('socket.io');
    
    const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
    const app = next({ dev });
    const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
    
    app.prepare().then(() => {
        const server = createServer((req, res) => {
            const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
            handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
        });
    
        const io = new Server(server, {
            cors: {
            origin: 'http://ipaddress:3001', // Update this to the origin you want to allow
            methods: ['GET', 'POST']
            }
        });
    
        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log('Client connected:', socket.id);
    
            socket.on('register', (userId) => {
            // Handle user registration
            });
    
            socket.on('send_message', ({ itemId, message, senderId, origin }) => {
                io.emit('new_message', { itemId, message, senderId, origin });
            });
    
            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('Client disconnected:', socket.id);
            // Handle user disconnection
            });
        });
    
        server.listen(3001, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('> Ready on http://ipaddress:3001');
        });
    });

    ---package.json
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node server.js",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
        "lint": "next lint"
      }



You made a typical mistake to hook your server to a dedicated port number (3001).
Like I showed in all related posts, such as this one, you have to let IIS decide which port to use.
        const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
        server.listen(port, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(`> Ready on http://ipaddress:${port}`);
        });

Note that you have to edit other locations where you hard coded port number.

@pryxen - Local: http://localhost:28864 The port you set in the IIS binding does not match the port 3001 you requested. Try to match them up.

Finally I got it, with the use of sir @Lex Li answer, I configure my server.js and make my web.config just like below
---server.js
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || 'ip address'
const port = process.env.PORT || 8888;

const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = createServer((req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
        handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    });

    const io = new Server(server, {
        cors: {
        origin: `http://${hostname}:${port}`, // Update this to the origin you want to allow
        methods: ['GET', 'POST']
        }
    });

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('Client connected:', socket.id);

        socket.on('register', (userId) => {
        // Handle user registration
        });

        socket.on('send_message', ({ itemId, message, senderId, origin }) => {
            io.emit('new_message', { itemId, message, senderId, origin });
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected:', socket.id);
        // Handle user disconnection
        });
    });

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
    });
});

---web.config
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>   
    <handlers>
        <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\node.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v20.10.0\node.exe" arguments=".\server.js">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
            <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="production" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Since the IIS is now taking control of the port. I update my web.config from this arguments=".\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next start" to this arguments=".\server.js" so it can execute the server.js. If I use this arguments=".\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next start", it will run the app too but the socket.io server will not start. I also added this <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="production" /> so it will execute the production mode.

Then you should accept your own answer, not mine.
